# Routing low-voltage shade power lines in drywall

Tags: electrical, usa

For way too many reasons to list, the contractor/sub/vendor placed the low-voltage power lines for shades too far away from the windows. We're going to be stuck doing a DIY solution to get those wires closer.

Any thoughts on how to channel these wires to be closer to the window? They don't need to be inside the window frame but do need to be closer.

EDIT: the wire needs to move 3-4 inches to the left in order to be hidden by the shade's valance.

The house is completed and ready for inspection so, yes, the drywall covers the framing around the window.

There are five windows like this. Opening the drywall is a little more complex in that it is completely finished and painted. The wire was misplaced during construction. If wired to the shade from its current position it will exit the drywall, be exposed for about three inches and then disappear behind the valance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hard to tell what we're looking at here. Is that loop of wire in the top photo the LV wiring? Is it still like that now? I'm presuming the drywall in the other pic is covering this window? Where do the LV wires need to end up? Have you considered just cutting the drywall back, drilling a hole to wherever the wire needs to be, then patching in the drywall again? Looks like the drywall hasn't been finished yet, so that should happen when it's finished - not like you're cutting into final finished walls...

Comment: I think you'll need to define, perhaps with some markup on your pictures, where the wires are now, how thick the studs are behind the drywall, and where the blind control needs the wires to be.

Comment: I added info by editing the question: The house is completed and ready for inspection. All drywall is finished and painted. The wire really needs to be 3-4 inches to the left of its current position for about 4-5 windows. The buyer's are thinking of opening a channel in the drywall, placing the wire and then mudding over the channel. I'm just looking for alternative solutions. Thanks.